# What does ENOENT mean when sending data over a socket?

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I am working on some embedded C code that posts data to a website over the HTTP protocol. The first bytes go well, chunked in 1024 byte buffers. At the end, though, the `send()` call fails with `errno=2` (ENOENT). I cannot find this error in the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/2/send), so I have no idea what goes wrong. My HTTP POST header says

```
Content-Length: 12517
```

which is the exact amount of bytes I am sending (it is a raw file post).

This is my code (`sockfd` is an correctly opened socket):

```
void send_all_n(int sockfd, char *buf, int buf_len) {
    int bytes_sent = 0;
    char *buf_ptr = buf;
    int failed = 0;

    do {
        bytes_sent = send(sockfd, buf_ptr, buf_len-bytes_sent, 0);
        if (bytes_sent > 0) {
            buf_ptr += bytes_sent;
        } else if (bytes_sent == -1) {
            switch(errno) {
                case EWOULDBLOCK:
                    usleep(100000);
                    break;
                default:
                    failed = 1;
                    break;
            }
        }
    } while (bytes_sent < buf_len && failed == 0);
}
```

Many 1024-byte buffers go well, until somewhere at the end, my logging says this:

```
2014-04-09 18:13:31 +0800 [D]: [network] wrote 328 bytes to host, buf_len=1024, bytesleft=696
2014-04-09 18:13:31 +0800 [D]: [network] wrote -1 bytes to host, buf_len=1024, bytesleft=1025
2014-04-09 18:13:31 +0800 [S]: [network] could not send data: errno=2
```

**Update**: if I add 1 second sleeps between the sending of the buffers, it works fine.

Comment: @hmjd just after the `bytes_sent = ` statement. I removed it from the code against clutter.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but if a buffer gets sent in more than 2 chunks your code will try to send too much and overrun `buf`.

Comment: Are you sure there is **no** call changing `errno` in between the `send()` that failed and the call that logs it? At least for debugging I'd add `perror("send() failed")` to the `switch()`'s `default` case.

Comment: Also you might like to add `EAGAIN` to do the same as `EWOULDBLOCK`. Another special case you might consider to handle is `EINTR`. The default action for the latter would be to just call to `continue`.

Comment: @alk, in my device, they have the same value.

Comment: you can use strerror which takes errno as argument  e.g. char str[]=strerror(ENOENT);

Comment: My logging screwed up the `errno`. I copy it into a local variable now and `EWOULDBLOCK` case gets eexcuted. Thanks, @alk. If you make your comment an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure there is **no** call changing `errno` in between the `send()` that failed and the call that logs it?

At least for debugging I'd add `perror("send() failed")` to the `switch()`'s `default` case.